# Segfault when deleting non-empty directory using C

Tags: c, directory, segmentation-fault, dirent.h

I am trying to delete a none-empty directory without system calls and without using extensive libraries. My code so far is...

```
int rmrf(char *path) {
    char* path_copy = (char *) malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(path_copy, path);
    DIR *directory = opendir(path_copy);
    struct dirent *entry = readdir(directory);
    while (entry != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, "..")) { //skip /. and /..
        } else if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) { //directory recurse
            strcat(path_copy, "/");
            strcat(path_copy, entry->d_name);
            rmrf(path_copy);
            remove(path);
        } else { //file delete
            strcat(path_copy, "/");
            strcat(path_copy, entry->d_name);
            remove(path_copy);
        }
        entry = readdir(directory);
    }
    closedir(directory);
    return 0;
}
```

my current file structure looks something like this...

```
Who
|---Region 1
    |---County 1
        |---SubCounty 1
    |---County 2
|---Region 2
    |---County 1
|---Region 3
```

currently I am getting seg faults but in different places as the day progresses. Earlier today I would get about two levels of recursion deep and then seg fault out but as of now I can't even make past a full level down. I can't figure out what is wrong and when I use gdb to look into the problem I get...

```
malloc.c: No such file or directory.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:

I have taken suggestions from paxdiablo and came up with the resulting function...

```
int rmrf(char *path) {
    char* path_copy = malloc(1024);
    DIR *directory = opendir(path);
    struct dirent *entry = readdir(directory);
    while (entry != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, "..")) { //skip /. and /..
        } else if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) { //directory recurse
            strcpy(path_copy, path);
            strcat(path_copy, "/");
            strcat(path_copy, entry->d_name);
            rmrf(path_copy);
            remove(path);
        } else { //file delete
            strcpy(path_copy, path);
            strcat(path_copy, "/");
            strcat(path_copy, entry->d_name);
            remove(path_copy);
        }
        entry = readdir(directory);
    }
    closedir(directory);
    free(path_copy);
    return 0;
}
```

however I am still getting a seg fault though it is getting further in the recursion. The gdb output for the seg fault is as followed...

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7dd1b20 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=32816) at malloc.c:3802
3802    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7dd1b20 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=32816) at malloc.c:3802
#1  0x00007ffff7a91184 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=32816) at malloc.c:2913
#2  0x00007ffff7ad51ba in __alloc_dir (statp=0x7fffffffe190, flags=0, close_fd=true, fd=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/opendir.c:247
#3  opendir_tail (fd=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/opendir.c:145
#4  __opendir (name=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/posix/opendir.c:200
#5  0x0000000000401bca in rmrf ()
#6  0x0000000000401c8d in rmrf ()
#7  0x0000000000401c8d in rmrf ()
#8  0x0000000000402380 in main ()
```

Thoughts?

Comment: If you catch the crash in a debugger (like you seem to be doing), then take a look at the call stack to find out where in *your* code it happens.

Comment: By the way, where in your code do you `free` the memory you allocate for `path_copy`?

Comment: I am not currently freeing the memory for path_copy because as I mentioned in paxdiablos answer I am unsure as to how I can free that memory but still pass the path when calling the function again. Can you explain freeing before leaving the function?

Comment: Just put the `free` call before you return from the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your *initial* code, you do this *once* when entering the function:

```
strcpy(path_copy, path);
```

Then you do this for *each* file or directory in the current directory:

```
strcat(path_copy, "/");
strcat(path_copy, entry->d_name);
```

That means, if you have the files `a`, `b` and `c` in your current directory `/xx`, the `path_copy` variable will cycle through:

```
/xx/a   /xx/a/b   /xx/a/b/c
```

rather than the correct:

```
/xx/a   /xx/b     /xx/c
```

With a sufficiently large number of files, you will easily blow out the 1024 bytes allocates for the path.

If you want to fix that then you should start the variable from scratch each time:

```
if ((strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0)) {
    if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
        strcpy(path_copy, path);
        strcat(path_copy, "/");
        strcat(path_copy, entry->d_name);
        rmrf(path_copy);
        remove(path);
    } else {
        sprintf(path_copy, "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);
        remove(path_copy);
    }
}
```

You'll note that I've modified your initial condition a little so that it makes more sense (only do the inner bit if the file is neither `.` nor `..`).

I've also shown, in the `else` clause, a shorter way of constructing the string to delete using `sprintf` rather than a set of `strcpy/strcat` calls. Feel free to do that in the `if` clause as well if you wish, I've left it using the old method so you can see all you needed to do was add the initial path.

And just a few extra points, applicable to your first and/or second code snippet:

- You should also make sure you *free* the memory you allocate at each level, immediately before returning from the function, between `closedir()` and `return`.
- You *never* need to cast the return value of `malloc` since a `void *` can be implicitly cast to any other type of pointer. In fact, it's dangerous to do so since it can hide certain subtle errors.
- Similarly, you *never* need to multiply by `sizeof(char)` - that is, by definition, always one.
- You can move the creation of `path_copy` to *before* the file/directory check since it's common to both parts.
- And, finally, you're going to have troubles if the directory you're processing doesn't actually exist since `opendir` will return NULL and you will immediately try to pass that to `readdir`.

---

With all that in mind, I'd start with the following program which actually *walks* the tree and prints out all the files it finds. Once you're happy with that, you can add back in the bit that deletes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int rmrf(char *path) {
    char *path_copy = malloc(1024);
    DIR *directory = opendir(path);
    if (directory != NULL) {
        struct dirent *entry = readdir(directory);
        while (entry != NULL) {
            if ((strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0)) {
                sprintf(path_copy, "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);
                if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
                    rmrf(path_copy);
                    puts(path);
                } else {
                    puts(path_copy);
                }
            }
            entry = readdir(directory);
        }
        closedir(directory);
    }
    free(path_copy);
    return 0;
}
```

The main code is just a driver to ensure thinks are set up correctly. Just make sure, before running, you don't have (in your current directory) a `paxtest` or `paxtest2` file or directory you want to keep around.

```
int main(void) {
    system("rm -rf paxjunk");
    system("mkdir paxjunk");
    system("touch paxjunk/0.txt");
    system("mkdir paxjunk/1");
    system("touch paxjunk/1/1.txt");
    system("mkdir paxjunk/2");
    system("touch paxjunk/2/2.txt");

    rmrf("paxjunk");
    puts("===");

    system("rm -rf paxjunk2");

    rmrf("paxjunk2");
    puts("===");

    system("rm -rf paxjunk");

    return 0;
}
```

When you run this, you should see it working okay:

```
paxjunk/0.txt
paxjunk/1/1.txt
paxjunk
paxjunk/2/2.txt
paxjunk
===
===
```

Comment: The last part of your response confuses me. If I free the memory allocated at each level (path_copy as that is the only thing allocated) before I leave the function how do I pass it for recursion?

Comment: @JJStamp, at the end of the function, all recursive calls that depend on that string have *already executed fully.* Hence it is safe to delete.

Comment: So by freeing before leaving you mean free before the return not before calling itself within the first else if, right?

Comment: @JJStamp: yes, I can see that "leaving the function" may have been misconstrued here as including "calling a sub-function".  Will clarify to ensure it's only "returning from the function". Hope that clears it up.

Comment: I updated my question as I am still getting a seg fault with your suggestions, hopefully I am implementing this correctly, so if you could take a look at it to make sure I am understanding you correctly that would be great!

Comment: @JJStamp: and I've updated my *answer* :-) Have a look at the code I put at the bottom and the bullet points explaining the issue. This code has been tested locally so should be good to go.

Comment: if I am still getting a seg fault when copy pasting your solution does that mean the problem isn't the code but that I am just running out of memory all together? I am extremely confused

Comment: @paxdiablo feeling the effects of blood loss yet?

Comment: @JJStamp, if you're crashing with the *exact* code I posted (including the main driver), I'd say there was something wrong with your environment :-/ If you're crashing using my function with your driver, put a `puts(path)` at the start of the function and see how deep it's going. It may be the depth is too high if, for example, you have symbolic links up to a parent directory, resulting in infinite recursion.

Comment: It may also be that the recursion level is not too high but the path is still getting beyond 1K. Printing out the path at the start of each level should hopefully indicate whether that's the case.

Comment: I figured it has to do with my environment because it works fine on my friends computer so I'll mark this as the answer thanks for all the help!